# socket in CLOSE wait situation caused nifi hang

Tags: hadoop, apache-nifi

Noticed nifi threads stuck in there when processing the memory/CPU intensive jobs. 
After dig deeper into it, and found the socket is in "CLOSE WAIT" situation. 
Could this be a reason (CLOSE_WAIT issue) caused nifi thread stuck? If yes, why there will be a close_wait issue for long running job, and how to solve it?

Comment: I think we'll need to see the thread dumps related to the threads you're referencing.  You can run bin/nifi.sh dump and it will put the stack dump into the logs/nifi-bootstrap.log

Comment: here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ctq6bvmuzpue6aw/dump.txt?dl=0

Comment: I don't see any CLOSE_WAIT in the file

Comment: @bryan bende, the CLOSE_WAIT is showed in the result of "netstat -p | grep java"   <br/>    tcp        1      0 klkl02.41995 hdppname5.8188 CLOSE_WAIT  97271/java  <br/>  tcp        0      0 klkl02.38596 si-nadc-ldaps ESTABLISHED 97271/java